# opengl for java(jogl)

Tags: opengl, netbeans, 3d, java-3d

I added OpenGL plugin to my IDE(netbeans) using:

Tools->Plugins->Downloaded->Add plugins

But I can't import it to my program;

```
import javax.media.opengl.GL;
```

How should I do this?

> Edit

while I want to install the plugin on a page write:

> The plugin Editor Library is requested
>   in version >= 1.29.2.8.2 (release
>   version 1) but only 2.10.2.10.2 (of
>   release version different from 1) was
>   found.  The following plugin is
>   affected:       GLSL editor

Comment: Please include your error message.

Comment: It doesn't have any error.but it don't know **opengl.GL**.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add a library for your project as if it were a plugin.

Add it like this:

Right click on your project > Properties > Libraries > Add JAR/Folder

That should do the trick. You may want to refresh and rebuild your project after that, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: It isn't **library** it is a **plugin**.

Comment: Well, in your question you called it a library (first line). Anyway, in order to have the classes on your IDEs classpath, the easiest thing to do is to add the needed jar as a library to the project.

Comment: sorry that's right.I add same plugin on netbeans 6.71 and it worked.but with netbeans 6.91 it has problems.all of my files are *.nbm

Comment: @mehdi: Can you find the same plugin for the version 6.91? It seems that it just isn't supported.

Comment: My plugin is for netbeans 6.7.1. If i must download it again for netbeans 6.9.1?

Comment: @mehdi: Probably. Your error message says that it doesn't work for that version.